# How can a C program without pointers keep giving me a segmentation fault error?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The program copied below is giving me a segmentation fault error.

I am very confused why this is happening. I read that segmentation errors only concern programs that use pointers, and I specifically got rid of my pointers because they were giving me too many such errors previously.

However, like I said, this program has none! I am quite vexed. Can anyone please chime in how to remedy this situation? I went through it line by line 10 times and did not see anything glaring.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    char engw [7] [3]  = {{'S','u','n'},{'M','o','n'},{'T','u','e'},{'W','e','d'},{'T','h','u'},{'F','r','i'},{'S','a','t'}};
    char engy [12] [3] = {{'J','a','n'},{'F','e','b'},{'M','a','r'},{'A','p','r'},{'M','a','y'},{'J','u','n'},{'J','u','l'},{'A','u','g'},{'S','e','p'},{'O','c','t'},{'N','o','v'},{'D','e','c'}};
    /*how do I get standard input?*/
    char test [3] = {0,0,0};
    test[0] = getchar();
    test[1] = getchar();
    test[2] = getchar();
    short domd = 7;
    short domm = 12;
    short daynum = 0;
    short counter = 0; 
    for (short q=0; q<domd; q++){
    if ((engw[q][0]==test[0])&&(engw[q][1]==test[1])&&(engw[q][2]==test[2])){
            counter=q;
    }
    char newword [32]  = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    short num = counter;
    FILE * wd;
    wd  = fopen("$1", "r");
    short w=0;
    while(((fgetc(wd)) != EOF)&& (num>=1)) {
            if ((fgetc(wd)) == ' ') {
                num--;
            }
            if (num == 1) {
                newword [w] = (( fgetc(wd)));
                w++;        
            }
            fclose(wd);
            short newstr=strlen(newword);
            for (short h=0; h<newstr; h++){
                char x=newword[h];
                printf ("%c", x);
            }
    }
    char space = getchar();
    printf ("%c", space);
    getchar(); /* for the space between the month and the day at hand */
    test[0] = getchar();
    test[1] = getchar();
    test[2] = getchar();
    for (short m=0; q<domm; m++){
            if ((engy[q][0]==test[0])&&(engy[q][1]==test[1])&&(engy[q][2]==test[2])){
                counter=m;
            }
            char newwordo [32]  = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
            short numo = counter;
            FILE * wd;
            wd  = fopen("$1", "r");
            short u=0;
            while(((fgetc(wd) != '\n') &&  (fgetc(wd)!= EOF)));
            while(((fgetc(wd)) != EOF)&& (num>=1)) {
                if ((fgetc(wd) == ' ')) {
                    numo--;
        }
                if (numo == 1) {
                    newwordo [u] = ((fgetc(wd)));
                    u++;        
        }
                fclose(wd);
                short newstro=strlen(newwordo);
                for (short k=0; k<newstro; k++){
                    char x=newwordo[k];
                    printf ("%c", x);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So by your logic program without explicit use of pointer cannot crash .

Comment: Run off the end of an array and into invalid memory.

Comment: Arrays are related to pointers. And you *do* have at least one pointer, one which you don't check if it's `NULL`. The `FILE*` returned by `fopen`.

Comment: Anyway, the way to solve crashes like this is to use a debugger. If you run a debug build in a debugger then you can catch the crash *in action* and locate where in your code it happens. You will also be able to examine variables and their values to see that they are okay.

Comment: Oh, and why do you close the file in the middle of the loops? That will *definitely* lead to *undefined behavior* when you next try to read from the file.

Comment: Use a debugger to find out where the segmentation fault occurs..

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary that only using pointers causes segmentation faults. Segmentation faults happen when you try to access any memory address that you are not allowed to. Pointers (that include file pointers, which you **are** using, by the way) are essentially addresses.

Chances are, that fopen failed and returned a null pointer. And that's an address that you definitely **cannot** access. So it's always advisable to check if (wd == null) before beginning to use it.

Alternatively, if you are wondering where the segfaults are happening, GDB is an excellent tool that will allow you to see the backtrace and find exactly which line your program crashed on.

Here's a tutorial on how to use GDB: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/